# PHP preg_match for dimension

Tags: php, regex

I was searching for hours to get a regular expression for matching dimension in a string.
Consider following types of strings,

```
120x200
100' X 130'
4 acres
0.54
0.488 (90x223)/ GIS0.78
90x160
100x149.7
143.76 X 453.52
6.13 per tax bill
120x378 per tax roll
```

I want the O/P contain only dimensions, even with 'X' or 'x'
From the above string, the expected output is,

```
120x200,100' X 130',0,0,90x223,90x160,100x149.7,143.76 X 453.52,0,120x378
```

Is there any possible reg-ex? or any other alternative?

Thanks

Comment: What is your current regex?

Comment: I didn't get any solution till.
Was trying to use something like /[0-9]{2}x[0-9]{3}/i, but then need to specify count.
I want a general expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
<?php

$str = <<<EOD
120x200
100' X 130'
4 acres
0.54
0.488 (90x223)/ GIS0.78
90x160
100x149.7
143.76 X 453.52
6.13 per tax bill
120x378 per tax roll
EOD;

$lines = explode("\n", $str);

foreach($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/-?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(\'|ft|yd|m|")?)\s*x\s*-?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\\2)?)/i', $line, $match)) {
        echo "{$match[1]}x{$match[3]}\n";
    } else {
        echo "0\n";
    }
}
```

You can add more units of measurement into the 3rd parenthesized expression if you want to match more things, but this matches whole numbers, real numbers, and optional units of measurement after.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?['"]?\s*[xX]\s*\d+(\.\d+)?['"]?
```

**demo** : http://regexr.com?386sf

However,it does not cover all of your cases,as they are too customized to be handled by regex.
I would recommend using a customized method to parse the input with different cases.

Comment: is there any ' or " missing. am getting error while trying this expression?
Thanks for the quick reply